# Still unsure about signed integer overflow in C++

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

In the following code I tested which form of overflow results in UB and causes therefore
an hard error in a `constexpr` context:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>

using T = int8_t;
int main() {    
    constexpr bool b = []{
        T x = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
        ++x; // GCC: UB, Clang: no UB
//        x += 1;
//        x = x + 1;
        return (x > std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
    }();

    return b;    
}
```

The preincrement gives an error (as I expected) for gcc but not for clang.

More strange is that the standard says that `++x` is the same as `x += 1`, but using this gives no more an error on gcc (and clang as before).

And further `x += 1` should be the same as `x = x + 1`, so the rhs is promoted to `int` and the result is implicitly converted. So, this should newer be UB.

So, the question is, which of the three statement really should be UB (I think only `++x`) and which compiler is correct?

Comment: It's always UB. UB doesn't mean an error will occur, it just means literally what it says; the *behavior* of your program is *undefined*. That doesn't mean it's not allowed to work how you expect; it just means the compiler is under no obligation to produce an executable that does.

Comment: I far as I know, the clang implementations should (or might be) interpreted into java runtime code (at least for Android), so that won't give you the same exceptions or/and behaviour as It is when you develop your C/C++ application. According to wikipedia, what clang compiler does is that analyzes the source code to build an internal representation of the program, called the intermediate representation (compiler -> front end compiler).

Comment: this isn't C. There's no C/C++ language. C and C++ are completely different languages

Comment: I don't agree at least that `x = x + 1` is UB, because `x` is promoted to `int` and no overflow occurs. And that should also apply to `x += 1`. Then an conversion applys back to `uint8_t`, and here the result is implementation-defined but not UB.

Comment: @wimalopaan Since c++20 `x = x + 1` is well defined. `x + 1` promoted to `int` first so no overflow happens and the assignment back to `int8_t` is now defined to work modulo 2^n. Whether that applies to `x += 1` and `++x` too I leave to the language lawyers. `int8_t` has been defined as two's-complement so the result of overflow should never be in question. It's silly C++ still calls it UB, stupid integer promotion breaking it all.

Comment: "I tested which form of overflow results in UB" You can't.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow And pre-C++20 narrowing signed casts were implementation-defined (aka worked in practice), not UB.

Comment: @IvanSilkin I don't know about android, but normally that's not the case. LLVM IR is then converted to native code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat right.

Comment: So is `++x` identical to `x += 1` and identical to `x = x + 1`? They aren't for classes. But integer types?

Comment: What about `signed char` as destination type: is that implementation-defined or is `signed char` also 2s-complement since c++20, so the conversion should be well-defined?

Comment: @Kyle and Yunnosch OP is using a linguistic shorthand. Most language-level operations which /would be/ UB outside of a constant expression are disallowed in a constant expression and make it ill-formed, /not/ UB. So yes, UB means anything can happen, but language-level "UB" inside a constant expression does not. And you can test for "UB" by putting it in a constant expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[expr.pre.incr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.pre.incr#1)

> The expression ++x is equivalent to x+=1.

[[expr.ass]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#6)

> The behavior of an expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = E1 op E2 except that E1 is evaluated only once.

But `x = x + 1` is not UB (integer promotion and narrowing integer conversion), so the original is well-formed. Therefore, GCC is wrong.

Comment: Well ok, then I will file a bug to gcc and see what the gcc people say.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105774

Comment: Simultaneous thoughts.